# how to access child elements of <ul>?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

while creating custom directive, I am trying to fetch html elements

```
'<div class="parent">', 
  '<ul class="item-list">', 
    '<li ng-repeat="item in ::items" class="item-element">{{item}}</li>', 
  '</ul>', 
'</div>', 
'<div class="selector"></div>'

link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
  var ta = element[0],
    $ta = element;
  var itemList = angular.element(ta.querySelector(".item-list"));
  console.log(itemList);
  var itemEl = itemList[0].children;
  console.log(itemEl);
}
```

itemEl displayed on console

```
 []
 0: li.item-element.ng-binding
 1: li.item-element.ng-binding
 2: li.item-element.ng-binding
 3: li.item-element.ng-binding
 length: 4
__proto__: Object
```

How can I fetch inner html and length of the `<ul>` in angularjs ?

Comment: Have you tried logging `ta` in console? Why are you using `element[0]` instead of `element`

Comment: What are you expecting from this code? What problems are you having?

Comment: I want to fetch data from item-list class.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know more about AJ but you can do it in jquery

```
$(".parent .item-list li").length;
```